# Php цикл for и операции

Tags: php, for

**всем привет, мне нужно создать циклические блоки через php, но при вот таком коде  `

```
$j = array();
for($i=1;$i<4;$i++) {
    $j[]= $i } :?>

<img src="<?php echo $i; ?>.gif">

<?php endfor ?>
```

вылезает ошибка syntax error ":" и тд, т.е как я понял ему мешает операция выполняемая при каждой итерации цикла, т.к без нее ошибок нет. Можете подсказать как правильно написать код в моем случае. Заранее спасибо)**

Comment: `<?php foreach(): ?> // <?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: Может __ему__ мешает `:`? Не думали о таком?

Comment: Да я видел, у него синтаксическая ошибка @u_mulder

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600419/endforeach-in-loops пример

Comment: @MoloF да эт я не вам, а автору)

Comment: кажется понял, спасибо всем.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$j = array();
for($i=1;$i<4;$i++) {
    $j[]= $i . '.gif';

}
?>

<html>
    <head><!-- тут мета и т.д.... --></head>
    <body>
        <?php foreach($j as $imgSrc){?>
            <img src="<?php echo $imgSrc; ?>" />
        <?php } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, тебе большое)

Comment: @Abraham всегда пожалуйста) Кстати - на форуме по правилам не пишут "Спасибо" а просто отмечают ответ верным. Это и есть благодарность.)